# Is it possible for quarks and charged leptons to 'oscillate' analogously to neutrinos?

Tags: particle-physics, neutrinos

In a hypothetical scenario where the coupling of the fermions to the gauge fields were extremely small, would it be possible to observe quark and charged leptons oscillate in the same manner as we observe neutrino oscillations today?

i.e. would it be possible for the flavour eigenstate of a quark/lepton produced in a weak interaction to be detected as a different flavour eigenstate at a distant detector due to the states propagating according to their mass eigenstates?

$$ \left| {\nu_{\alpha}(T)} \right>  = \sum_iU^*_{\alpha i} \; e^{ip\cdot x} \left| \nu_i \right> $$

Comment: see https://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.1216v3.pdf

Comment: The Cabibbo–Kobayashi–Maskawa (CKM) matrix mixes the flavor eigenstates of quarks (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabibbo%E2%80%93Kobayashi%E2%80%93Maskawa_matrix) CP violations mix d, s and b quarks and u, c and t quarks.  The weak interaction partners of mass eigenstates of down type quarks d'. s' and b' are according to d, s and b and similarly up-type quarks, u′, c′ and t′, in terms of u, c, and t.

Comment: @annav ; thanks for the reference. The paper is rather nuanced, but it seems like the short answer is 'no' because charged leptons participate in weak interactions as mass eigenstates. I would still be interested in knowing about the situation for quarks though.

Comment: You might well have missed *the gist* of this delightful [paper](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1126-6708/2007/09/116): There is *no qualitative difference* between charged leptons and neutrinos coupling to W±. It is the larger *mass differences* of charged leptons that lead to absurdly small oscillation lengths (Angstroms!) and coherence lengths to make realistic oscillations inaccessible and unobservable. Btw, the strength of the gauge coupling is irrelevant here. It is only the leptons' mass differences that make all the difference!