# Can charged leptons undergo oscillation?

Tags: particle-physics, neutrinos, beyond-the-standard-model

Neutrino oscillation is an observed fact while charged lepton oscillation is not. Unlike neutrinos, is it possible for the charged leptons to oscillate, theoretically? In other words, is there anything that forbids the oscillation of charged lepton in principle?

Comment: [Duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/284965/is-it-possible-for-quarks-and-charged-leptons-to-oscillate-analogously-to-neut).

Comment: ***If*** they were produced coherently (***how***?) have you estimated the oscillation length of the superposition states?

Answer (score 4):

No, lepton oscillation does not happen, because we define e, µ and τ to be the mass eigenstates of the charged leptons. We then define the three neutrinos $\nu_e$, $\nu_\mu$, and $\nu_\tau$ to be the neutrinos corresponding to these three charged leptons.

If we did it the other way around, and defined $\nu_e$, $\nu_\mu$, and $\nu_\tau$ to be the mass eigenstates of the neutrinos, and e, µ and τ, to be the charged lepton states corresponding to these neutrino mass eigenstates, then charged leptons would oscillate, but neutrinos would not.

Although there's no reason we couldn't define things this way in theory, it would be a bad idea in practice, because generating mass eigenstates of charged leptons is nearly automatic, whereas generating mass eigenstates of neutrinos is quite difficult.

However, this argument shows that there is symmetry between neutrinos and leptons, and that the only reason that lepton oscillation doesn't happen and neutrino oscillation does is our definitions of e, µ, τ, $\nu_e$, $\nu_\mu$, and $\nu_\tau$.

Why don't the mass eigenstates of the neutrinos correspond to the mass eigenstates of the charged leptons? There's no reason they have to in the Standard Model, and it turns out they don't.

Comment: You make it sound as though this is a question of successful definitions or not, when the salient difference is mass differences. In a world of charged lepton masses differing by just a little, charged lepton weak (production/detection) eigenstates would oscillate as exuberantly as neutrinos...

Answer (score 1):

According to https://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.1216.pdf - the answer is most likely yes.  If I read the paper correctly (and I am only an engineer, not a scientist) the reason is the mass difference between the particles.

From the bullet points at the end:
Charged leptons e, µ and τ do not oscillate into each other because they are mass eigenstates. Since in β decays and muon decays the production of µ ± and τ
± is kinematically forbidden, there are no charged lepton oscillations associated with these processes.

Comment: You say that the paper you link to [Do charged leptons oscillate] says the answer is most likely "yes". At the very end, the paper says "Thus, the short answer to the question raised in the title of this paper  is ‘no’, at least if no new physics is involved." Are these answers supposed to be different?

Comment: @Peter Shor. Well, the answer is "no, but yes, but not really". Mass eigenstates never oscillate, even for neutrinos, but production groupings do or do not, depending on coherence features, which the paper discusses. Charge leptons are so heavy and spread in mass that no realistic oscillations can happen.

Comment: @PeterShor my answer was Yes to his question "In other words, is there anything that forbids the oscillation of charged lepton in principle?"  and then answered why that is according to the paper.

Comment: The question in the *title* is "Can charged leptons undergo oscillation?" You need to be more careful about specifying which question you're answering.

Comment: His question was opposite his title....